# Chaining Observables creates nested observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm refactoring some code I've written and I'm trying to chain my observables together.  I had code which made a request and returned an `Observable<Response>` but now that my access token is stored using ionic storage, I'm running into some issue when I attempt to make a request

```
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    var observable = Observable.fromPromise(
        this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)
    )

    let request = observable.map(options =>  super.request(url, options));
    return request;
}
```

When I attempt to create my options I need to obtain an Access token which now lies in ionic storage,  I'm trying to map the options to the request but I'm getting the wrong return value when I attempt to do so.

My request is return an `Observable<Observable<Response>>` instead of an `Observable<Response>`

How can I return a `Observable<Response>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with ionic, but it seems you are trying to flatten out Observable of Observers to an Observable.

If that is the case, you could use **mergeMap** which  will merge the Observables

It would look something like this:

```
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    var observable = Observable.fromPromise(
        this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)
    )
    return observable.mergeMap(options =>  super.request(url, options));
  }
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I've edited your answer to the resolution